# How to assign awk result variable to an array and is it possible to use awk inside another awk in loop

Tags: bash, shell, csv, awk

I've started to learn bash and totally stuck with the task. I have a comma separated csv file with records like:

```
id,location_id,organization_id,service_id,name,title,email,department
1,1,,,Name surname,department1 department2 department3,,
2,1,,,name Surname,department1,,
3,2,,,Name Surname,"department1 department2, department3",, e.t.c.
```

I need to format it this way: *name* and *surname* must start with a capital letter

- add an email record that consists of the first letter of the name and full surname in lowercase
- create a new csv with records from the old csv with corrected fields.

I split csv on records using awk ( cause some fields contain fields with a comma between quotes *"department1 department2, department3"* ).

```
#!/bin/bash
input="$HOME/test.csv"

exec 0<$input

while read line; do

awk -v FPAT='"[^"]*"|[^,]*' '{ 
  ...
}' $input)

done
```

inside awk {...} (NF=8 for each record), I tried to use certain field values ($1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8):

```
#it doesn't work 

IFS=' ' read -a name_surname<<<$5 # Field 5 match to *name* in heading of csv

# Could I use inner awk with field values of outer awk ($5) to separate the field value of outer awk $5 ? 
# as an example:                                  
# $5="${awk '{${1^}${2^}}' $5}"
# where ${1^} and ${2^} fields of inner awk
  
name_surname[0]=${name_surname[0]^}
name_surname[1]=${name_surname[1]^}
  
$5="${name_surname[0]}' '${name_surname[1]}"

email_name=${name_surname[0]:0:1}
email_surname=${name_surname[1]}
domain='@domain'

$7="${email_name,}${email_surname,,}$domain" # match to field 7 *email* in heading of csv
```

how to add field values ($1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8) to array and call *function join*  for each *for loop* iteration to add record to new csv file?

```
function join { local IFS="$1"; shift; echo "$*"; }
result=$(join , ${arr[@]})
echo $result >> new.csv
```

Comment: You don't need to involve bash (except to call awk once) and you don't need to call awk within awk. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input (showing representative values, not just plaseholder strings like "name" everywhere as in your current sample input) and the expected output given that input and then we can help you. Use `...@example.com` for the fake email addresses you want added as that's what that domain exists for.

Comment: Don't use while read loops in shell just to manipulate text btw - see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be what you're trying to do (using gawk for FPAT as you already were doing) but without more representative sample input and the expected output it's a guess:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
BEGIN {
    OFS = ","
    FPAT = "[^"OFS"]*|\"[^\"]*\""
}
NR > 1 {
    n = split($5,name,/\s*/)
    $7 = tolower(substr(name[1],1,1) name[n]) "@example.com"
    print
}
' "${@:--}"
```

```
$ ./tst.sh test.csv
1,1,,,Name surname,department1 department2 department3,nsurname@example.com,
2,1,,,name Surname,department1,nsurname@example.com,
3,2,,,Name Surname,"department1 department2, department3",nsurname@example.com,
```

I put the awk script inside a shell script since that looks like what you want, obviously you don't need to do that you could just save the awk script in a file and invoke it with `awk -f`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Could you explain in more detail:  `"${@:--}"` as I understand (in according to [link](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) ) this is ${parameter:offset}  and @ - this is all positional parameters, but why there is a double dash? When I deleted one dash nothing was changed.

Comment: It's not `${parameter:offset}`, it's the first item in the list at that link, i.e. `${parameter:-word}`. The `:-` in  the middle is the operator. In the same way that `x="${@:-foo"}` means "set x to the args if any are present, otherwise set x to foo", `cmd "${@:--}"` means "run cmd on the args if any are present, otherwise run cmd on stdin (`-`)". It's a common way to write shell scripts that can be called as `script file` or `cat file | script` while passing the input to some other internal command.

Answer (score 0):

Completely working answer by Ed Morton.

If it may be will be helpful for someone, I added one more checking condition: if in CSV file more than one email address with the same name - index number is added to email local part and output is sent to file

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
input="$HOME/test.csv"
exec 0<$input

awk '
BEGIN {
  OFS = ","
  FPAT = "[^"OFS"]*|\"[^\"]*\""
}

(NR == 1) {print} #header of csv
(NR > 1) {

  if (length($0) > 1) { #exclude empty lines
    count = 0
    n = split($5,name,/\s*/)
    email_local_part = tolower(substr(name[1],1,1) name[n])
   
    #array stores emails from csv file
    a[i++] = email_local_part
    
    #find amount of occurrences of the same email address
    for (el in a) {
      ret=match(a[el], email_local_part)
  
      if (ret == 1) { count++ }
    } 

    #add number of occurrence to email address
    if (count == 1) { $7 = email_local_part "@abc.com" }
    else { --count; $7 = email_local_part count "@abc.com" }

    print 
  }
} 
' "${@:--}" > new.csv
```